# Semantic consequence as a partial order

Tags: logic, equivalence-relations

It is known that semantic consequence is a binary relation over a set of well formed formulas Form(V) (where V is a set of propositional variables). Writing **A**⊨**B** means that **B** is a semantic consequence of **A**, i.e. every interpretation *f* for which **A** is true (f(**A**)=1) is an interpretation for which **B** is true (if f(**A**)=1 then f(**B**)=1). 
This binary relation ⊨ is clearly not a partial order in Form(V) as it can be easily shown that it is not antisymmetric. It *is* however a partial order in Form(V)/≡ where ≡ means “semantic equivalence” (an equivalence relation).

Is the POSET (Form(V)/≡, ⊨) a lattice?

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean that $\models$ is not *antisymmetric*, because it is definitely transitive. Indeed, without taking the quotient we can have different formulas $A$ and $B$ that are equivalent (so $A \models B$ and $B \models A$).

Other than that, transitivity and reflexivity are clear. So $\models$ defines a preorder on the set of formulas, and so we get a partial order on the set of equivalence classes under the relation of "semantic equivalence" as you call it.

This partial order actually has quite a nice structure, namely that of a Boolean algebra (assuming your logic is Boolean), and what you are essentially describing is the [Lindenbaum-Tarksi algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindenbaum%E2%80%93Tarski_algebra). Note that the Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra is usually formulated in *provability*, but this will coincide with semantics because of the soundness and completeness theorems.

**Edit:** I just noticed you were talking about propositional logic. The Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra is actually formulated for full first-order logic. So you get the propositional case as a special case.

Comment: You are absolutely right, it is transitive but not antisymmetric! I shall correct it right away. Thank you for your answer!